# How to make ag search "non-standard" langauge files?

Tags: ag

I'm using Silver Searcher, `ag`, version 2.1.0 on Ubuntu. I'm trying to search for the string `aStar` in Haskell files in the current directory tree. (The files are text files with extension `.hs`.)

The behaviour isn't what I expect.

```
$ ag aStar
```

finds no matches.

```
ag --haskell aStar
```

finds no matches.

```
ag --haskell --all-text aStar
```

finds the correct matches in the `.hs` files.

```
ag --all-text aStar
```

finds the correct matches in `.hs` files, plus a bunch in some temporary files I don't want searched.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong, and why the `--haskell` flag doesn't make `ag` search the Haskell files?

Comment: `ag aStar` works for me. Can you put contents of your `.hs` files?

Comment: Further investigation shows it's the _path_ that's important. The files I'm after are in `advent18/src/advent18.hs` and aren't found. But if I `cd advent18` first, the files are found in the relative `./src/` directory. It seems the `--all-text` flag is making `ag` search deeper in the tree.